# What does it mean when we say $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition, implicit-differentiation

If we have an equation that's true for all $(x,y)$ in a set $S$, for example:
$y = 2x^2 + 3x$

We say that its derivative is:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = 4x + 3$

However, if we use the definition of the derivative on the left half $f(x) = y$, we get:
$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y - y}{h} = 0$

This would mean that either:

- Whenever $y = 2x^2 + 3x \rightarrow 0=4x+3$, which is false
- $\frac{dy}{dx}$ doesn't always mean "the derivative of $f(x) = y$"

The same problem also happens with implicit differentiation:

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$
$2x + \frac{dy^2}{dx} = 0$
$2x + lim_{h\to0}\frac{y^2 - y^2}{h} = 0$
$2x = 0$  (not equivalent to $x^2+y^2=1$)

All I did to get that result was to use the limit definition of the derivative on $\frac{dy}{dx}$ instead of leaving it as it is and isolating it.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, by $x$ and $y$, I am referring to variables in a two-variable equation. I'm not using "y" to mean "f(x)".

Comment: Why does $f(x+h) =y$ in your third equation ?

Comment: How do you write $y=f(x+h)$ and $y=f(x)$. $y$ is not an independent variable, it changes too.

Comment: Your two equations $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y - y}{h} = 0$$ exhibit a misunderstanding. The variable $y$ takes on different values depending on the input, and so you may not assume that $f(x+h)$ and $f(x)$ give the same value of $y$, as you do implicitly in the second of those two equations.

Comment: This confusion can  be avoided if you just explicitly state what variables $y$ is a function of. So by writing $y(x) = 2x^2+3x$ you see that $f(x+h) - f(x)$ is not $y-y$ but $y(x+h) - y(x)$ which is not identitcal to zero.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/oRe7Q

Comment: Of course, in that picture you have not told Mathematica that $y$ is a function of $x$ so the result is zero (just like if you had written `D[ 17, x]`). The correct way would be to write `D[y[x], x]`. If the function $y$ is defined then you get $\frac{dy}{dx}$ back, otherwise it just gives you the symbolic result $y'(x)$.

Comment: @Winther: Why is $y$ a function of $x$? It's just a variable in an equation that happens to be true for all $(x, y)$ belonging to a certain $S$...

Comment: Because $y = 2x^2 +3x$ is not true for all $x$ and $y$. The solutions to this equation defines a solution-set $A = \{(x,y) : y = 2x^2+3x\}$. This again implicitly defines a function $y = y(x)$. The same goes with other examples like $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (though the solution-set here defines two functions to be strickt $y(x) =\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$).

Comment: @Winther: Ok, I think I understand. So we can't just take the derivative of a string of operations by defining it like this: http://imgur.com/JRzuTbu and saying that $\forall (a,b) \in S: f(a) = g(b) \rightarrow \forall (a,b) \in S\ derivative[f(a)] =\ derivative[g(b)]$. We always need to have a function having $x$ as a variable when we want to derive with respect to x, and in this case, the equation implies that the function is $y(x) = 2x^2 + 3x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is read "the derivative of the variable $y$ with respect to the variable $x$". Actually, this refers to the derivative of the function that relates the variables.

If $y=2x^2+3x$ and $y=f(x)$, then $f(x)=2x^2+3x$ and $f(x+h)=2(x+h)^2+3(x+h) \neq y$. This is your mistake.

The definition is for the derivative of a function, not of a variable.
$y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x+h)$ are different ways of relating the variables, and that is what causes a zero result (if both hold for all small values of $h$, this would mean that $y$ is constant with respect to $x$, so the derivative is zero).

You have the right to say that $x$ and $y$ are variables and that $y$ is not only an expression for $f(x)$, but it must be clear what function you are trying to differentiate. And remember that $y=f(x)$ is an equation relating the variables as much as $x^2+y^2=1$ is

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition,

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
&=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2(x+h)^2 + 3(h+x) - 2x^2 + 3x}{h}\\
&=& \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{4xh + 3h + h^2}{h}\\
&=& \lim_{h\to 0} \left(4x + 3 + h \right)\\
&=& 4x + 3
\end{eqnarray}

Writing $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y - y}{h} = 0$ is not correct.

Since $y$ is a variable that is dependent on $x$, $y$ is function of $x$ and can be written as $y = f(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Your reasoning is wrong in here:

$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y - y}{h} = 0$

In fact, $\lim_{h\to0} f(x+h) = f(x) + h \cdot g(x)$ and it is exactly this $g(x)$ which is the value of interest and which is the derivative. In many cases, $g(x)$ can be evaluated without using calculus.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to evaluate a derivative without using calculus. Evaluating a derivative *is* calculus.

Comment: @MattSamuel For the purpose of obtaining the first derivative (this is what the OP asks), $\lim_{h\to0} f(x+h) = f(x) + h \cdot g(x)$ ist fine and terms of higher order in $h$ are not of importance.

Comment: For your other comment concerning calculus: the definition of all the nice operations and rules in calculus makes it necessary that  the above limit exists _before_ you apply the rules of calculus. To give a non-trivial example: $\cos(x+h) = \cos(h) \cos(x) - \sin(h) \sin(x)$ by trig. addition  theorems and, near $h=0$,  $\sin(h) \simeq h$ by geometric construction. Hence $\lim_{h\to0} \cos(x+h) = \cos(x) - h \sin(x) + \cal O (h^2)$  and therefore the $g(x)$ which I defined becomes $-\sin(x)$. So   for $f(x) = \cos(x)$, $f' (x) = -\sin(x)$ without calculus.

Comment: But $f'(x)$ can *always* be computed without calculus in this sense. It's not just in special cases.

Comment: I think writing $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h) = f(x) + hg(x)$ is bad notation here and just leads to confusion (for one thing the left hand side evaluates to $f(x)$ under the normal interpretation). What you mean is something like $f(x+h) \simeq f(x) + hg(x)$ when $h$ is small or more precise $f(x+h) = f(x) + hg(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^2)$.

Comment: @Winther Yes $f(x+h) = f(x) + hg(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^2)$ puts it right. I was merely reflecting the notation in the OPs question.